# Apply non-linear transformation to graphics object

Tags: graphics, geometry, geometric-transform

I would like to define some simple geometric primitives (e.g. points and lines) and see what happens when I transform them by a non-linear transformation (in my case $(x,y)\mapsto (\sqrt x,\sqrt y)$). The result should be an image showing $\{(\sqrt x, \sqrt y)|(x,y)\in X\}$, where $X$ is some set I defined before, like union of points and lines.

===

I tried playing with `TransformedRegion`. I can apply it to a single line, but for example `{Line[p1,p2],Line[p2,p3]}` is *not a correctly specified region*. Also, putting `TransformedRegion[Line[p1,p2],F]` (for some defined function F) to `Graphics` does not work, since "*TransformedRegion is not a Graphics primitive or directive*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things to discuss here.

**TransformedRegion output**

The output of [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) is a region object. In general, to view a region object, you need to use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) or [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion) on it. The exception is if [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) returns a primitive region, e.g., [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point), [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line), etc., in which case you can just use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) to view it. For example, here is a trivial transformation where [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) is able to return a primitive region:

```
reg = Line[{{1, 0}, {5, 1}}];
new = TransformedRegion[reg, RotationTransform[Pi/4]]
```

> Line[{{{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {2 Sqrt[2], 3 Sqrt[2]}}}]

You can use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) to view this primitive:

```
Graphics[new]
```

[image]

Here is your square root transformation, where [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) is unable to create a primitive region:

```
new = TransformedRegion[reg, Sqrt]
```

> TransformedRegion[Line[{{1, 0}, {5, 1}}], Sqrt]

For this kind of output, you need to use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) or [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion):

```
Region[new]
```

[image]

**TransformedRegion input**

The input to [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) should be a region object. This is why `Line[p1, p2]` works and `{Line[p1, p2], Line[p2, p3]}` does not work. If you want to transform the union of the two lines, use [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion):

```
reg = RegionUnion[
    Line[{{1, 0}, {3, 1}}],
    Line[{{0, 2}, {3, 0}}]
];
new = TransformedRegion[reg, Sqrt];
Region[new, PlotRange -> {{0,Sqrt[3]},{0,Sqrt[2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can put together what I need with these. Another question is, however, whether using `Region` is actually the best way to go. Are there also some other nice possibilities?

Comment: Also, is there a way to increase the precision? I tried the following code:
`a = {.1, .2}; b = {.15, .1}; c = {.3, .6}; d = {.4, .5};
Region[TransformedRegion[
  RegionUnion[Line[{a, b}], Line[{a, c}], Line[{b, c}], Line[{c, d}], 
   Line[{b, d}]], {Indexed[#, 1]^2, Indexed[#, 2]^2} &]]`.
The result does not show the transformed edge (a,b). I can see this edge if I remove, e.g., Line[{b,d}] from the union.

Comment: @OnDragi I think the issue is that Region is having difficulty figuring out the region bounds. If you include something like `PlotRange -> {{0, .2}, {0, .4}}` to your Region call, it should show the missing line.